# UI technology for segmentation and consolidation (portal alternative)

Tags: java, model-view-controller, user-interface, portal

I'm looking for a preferably Java-based technology that is able to:

- Separate development tasks between developers and does not requires them to access all the UI for development and testing. I'd like to create separate groups who develop the UI on their own.
- Consolidate the end results as a coherent application.

Yeah, I know, this is what portals and portlet containers are for, however I'm looking for alternative technology solutions - if there is any.

For example I can think of the followings:

- Spring MVC with clear separations on the scopes and "clever" merge process
- Struts actions and pages with clear separations on the scopes and merge of the configuration

Update: I haven't specified a few more requirements, but I need SEO, friendly urls, and do not consider Wicket (because it is hard to find developers) and JSF (because it has limitations I do not like).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've concluded that our way would be SpringMVC-based, [further discussion might continue at Spring forum](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?112003-Spring-WebMVC-annotations-for-multiple-teams&p=371958)

Answer (score 0):

We use [Vexi](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/vexi/wiki/BuildRelease) - here's [a demo](http://emanate-project.org/vexi_demo/) - with a lot of success, mainly because we maintain it.  Documentation is fairly thorough but not well organized online at the moment and the website is broken due to Sourceforge changes (thanks SF.net).

SEO is not really a feature because the applications 'launch' out of the browser rather than exist inside them.  However it is definitely an alternative technology!

It's a shame I can't show you the apps I'm working on at the moment, because they look great.  Our online profile for Vexi is dire though.

Comment: Unfortunately this is a no-go, because it is an applet-based solution, and that way we have no SEO. We are looking for straight HTML solution.